# how to show login username in php

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

how to show login username on home page
suppose if user name is admin when admin user log in own account then home page show

this username is admin

please see the links
now its showing like this
http://www.koolfree.com/ImageUpload/uploads/1380106000.jpg

and i want like this
http://www.koolfree.com/ImageUpload/uploads/1380025395.jpg

please help me to fix this issue 
thanks

this is mysql tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `member` (
  `mem_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `picture` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mem_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

This is index.php file

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();    
    //Unset the variables stored in session
    unset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']);
    unset($_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']);
    unset($_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME']);
?>
<form name="loginform" action="login_exec.php" method="post">
<table width="309" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <!--the code bellow is used to display the message of the input validation-->
         <?php
            if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && is_array($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && count($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) >0 ) {
            echo '<ul class="err">';
            foreach($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] as $msg) {
                echo '<li>',$msg,'</li>'; 
                }
            echo '</ul>';
            unset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']);
            }
        ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="116"><div align="right">Username</div></td>
    <td width="177"><input name="username" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right">Password</div></td>
    <td><input name="password" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right"></div></td>
    <td><input name="" type="submit" value="login" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

connection.php file

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "simple_login";
$prefix = "";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Could not select database");
?>
```

this is  login_exec.php file

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('connection.php');

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    //Sanitize the POST values
    $username = clean($_POST['username']);
    $password = clean($_POST['password']);

    //Input Validations
    if($username == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($password == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }

    //If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
    if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    }

    //Create query
    $qry="SELECT * FROM member WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['mem_id'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['username'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['password'];
            session_write_close();
            header("location: home.php");
            exit();
        }else {
            //Login failed
            $errmsg_arr[] = 'user name and password not found';
            $errflag = true;
            if($errflag) {
                $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
                session_write_close();
                header("location: index.php");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
?>
```

this is auth.php file

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();
    //Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
    if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '')) {
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

and this is home.php file

```
<?php
    require_once('auth.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p align="center" class="style1">Login successfully </p>
<p align="center">This page is the home, you can put some stuff here......</p>
<p align="center"><a href="index.php">logout</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to print out the username, since you set it in a session.

Provided you have `session_start()` at the top of your member's home page.

```
<?php 
    print $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'];
?>
```

Should do the trick, seeing as that is set to the username.

A Quick note, try using something like Mysqli or PDO, because the mysql library isn't being developed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your home.php file:

```
...
<p align="center">username: <?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']; ?></p>
<p align="center" class="style1">Login successfully </p>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php 
        echo $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'];
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   session_start();
   require_once('auth.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
font-size: 36px;
font-weight: bold;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p align="center" class="style1">Username: <?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']; ?> </p>
<p align="center" class="style1">Login successfully </p>
<p align="center">This page is the home, you can put some stuff here......</p>
<p align="center"><a href="index.php">logout</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```